# How has this view and control been done?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, user-interface

The image is attached below. Basically it is the popular photo editing app Snapseed. When you touch drag on an image that is being edited a table like view animates in to visibility on top of the image with its options as seen below in the image. The neatest part is that it vanishes on removing the finger from the screen and you perform the selection from one of the 5 options below in that table like view by continuing to touch drag in the upward or downward direction immediately after touch dragging on the image to make the menu appear. Once selection is made, it passes back the selection to the parent and vanishes. Any ideas on how this might have been done?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view with the buttons is probably hidden until the view with the image detects a touch, whereupon it executes the **touchesBegan:withEvent:** method, which is part of the UIResponder class. Most views subclass UIResponder, so this is a built-in method, along with **touchesEnded:withEvent:**. When touchesEnded:withEvent: executes, the button view is dismissed. (It either hides immediately or it animates the alpha value until is disappears.)

---

More info

Here is some code from the kal Calendar by Keith Lazuka. This code looks at the position where the touch ended to determine what "tile" on the calendar is hit. I suppose the same thing could be used here to determine which "button" is selected in your example.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self receivedTouches:touches withEvent:event];
}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self receivedTouches:touches withEvent:event];
}

 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
 CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
 UIView *hitView = [self hitTest:location withEvent:event];

 //[self receivedTouches:touches withEvent:event];

 if ([hitView isKindOfClass:[KalTileView class]]) {
 KalTileView *tile = (KalTileView*)hitView;

 if (tile.belongsToAdjacentMonth) {
 if ([tile.date compare:[KalDate dateFromNSDate:logic.baseDate]] == NSOrderedDescending) {
 [delegate showFollowingMonth];
 } else {
 [delegate showPreviousMonth];
 }
 self.selectedTile = [frontMonthView tileForDate:tile.date];
 } else {
 //self.selectedTile = tile;
 }
 }
 self.highlightedTile = nil;
 }
```

The key to this is in the first three lines of code in the touchesEnded method.

hitTest:withEvent: is an instance method of UIView that tells you which view was hit when the touchesEnded event fires, based on the point location where the touches ended occurs.

As you can see in this example code, it does return a UIView instance (or something subclassing UIView). Once you know which view was identified, to code can be written to take the desired action.

Comment: That's a start. And how about dragging to get the selection on the menu? Any clue on the computation behind that? The threshold of a drag to get an option highlighted/selected?

Comment: This can be done with button events, there are some UIControlEventTouchDrag-Outside -Enter -Inside -Exit.

Comment: So there are mechanisms to figure out how much upwards or downwards the drag was in order to select the appropriate item in the menu?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a simple UIView, added as subview, shown with bringSubviewToFront. What happens when you tap on the image again while the menu is shown?

Comment: When you touch drag, menu appears AND you need to maintain the touch on the screen. As soon as you take your finger off screen the menu vanishes. So you touch drag, menu appears and you keep dragging up or down to make/highlight the selection in the menu. Once what you want is chosen, you release your finger from the screen and it takes the selection in.