# Create Custom button like human Hand

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton

As a part of my app i need to fire a method while clicking any where inside a human hand image. Human hand image is placed in a image view. i need to add a button in-spite of adding gestures. Is it possible to create a custom button like human hand exactly show in the image below?

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom `UIButton` add the image hand as its `backgroundImage` or `setImage`. Then use /assign this image inside. Like below:

```
    handButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [handButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handImage_touch) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [handButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"handIMAGE.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    handButton.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    [self.view addSubview:handButton];

-(void)handImage_touch{
   // do anything
}
```

Comment: x, y, width, height will give a rectangle

Comment: i have tested exactly what u said.its working but i need to fire the function with in the black border around the hand.that i have mentioned in that image.

Answer (score 1):

I think at first you have to make polygon which fit to your image. And then you can use `touchesBegan:withEvent:` to get the coordinate of touch point and judge whether the point is inside of polygon or not.

Here is similar question like yours.

[How to get particular touch Area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450967/how-to-get-particular-touch-area)

I think this is a little difficult work, so maybe you would better use cocos2d library which have collision judgement function.

[image]

http://box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=7487

But also I think iOS is well constructed for handling touch, so this is beneficial effort for you.